# How can I return a specific value for LINQ if nothing is found?

Tags: c#, linq

It seems I've stumbled my way onto LINQ and have only just managed to see its usefulness. I'm unsure if I'm asking too much of it, or if I'm not doing things correctly. I have the following clumsy code,

```
class CStation{
    public String Make;
    public List<ulong> TunedStations;
}

List<List<ulong>> mStations=(from t in Radios where t.Make==aMake select t.TunedStations).ToList();
if(mStations.Count!=0)
    return mStations[0];
return null;
```

Functional yes, but could I some how do this with LINQ?

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`, perhaps? (In this case the "specific value" is `null` which should work nicely.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var myDefault = ......;

return (from t in Radios 
        where t.Make==aMake 
        select t.TunedStations)
       .FirstOrDefault() ?? myDefault ;
```

or as a lambda

```
    var myDefault = ......;
    
    return Radios.Where(t => t.Make == aMake)
           .FirstOrDefault() ?? myDefault ;
```

These will return the first item in the collection or your default (or just omit `?? myDefault` if you want to return null)

Answer (score 6):

Just use

```
return (from t in Radios where t.Make==aMake select t.TunedStations).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Just to note, the default here since it's an object type is null.